# Getting an error while trying to map a list of objects

Tags: java, list, stream

I'm trying to map below list :

```
mappedCustomers = customers.stream().map(e ->e.setLastName("e")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Customer Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;

String firstName;

String lastName;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

But I'm getting this error:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that void conforms to R
> [image]

Comment: Give the types of your variables and at least customer class.

Comment: Your method return void but map is expecting some return value, if you want to use a setter consider use a forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map function from the Stream API, is expecting a function that return a value.

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

However setters return value is void (no return value at all), therefore your code does not comply with the map method signature, if you want to iterate over a collection and execute an operation you could use forEach

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
```

No need to do the collection as you initial collection will be the same but it will contain your modification.

```
customers.stream().forEach(x -> x.setLastName("e"))
```

Answer (score 1):

`map()` returns a new stream, so you can chain another operation if you need, but your mapping method has to return something for this to work.
Since you provided a setter that returns `void`, your code won't compile.

In your case, `forEach()` would be simpler.

```java
customers.stream().forEach(e -> e.setLastName("e"));
```